# Sorting list according to other list in python not working when second list contains numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, numpy

The standard way to sort a list a based on list b, is to zip them together and use sorted, like

```
sorted(zip(b,a))
```

However, if two elements in b are equal, it will automatically proceed to try to sort according to a, and that sometimes causes problems. Consider for example

```
import numpy as np
a=[np.array([4,5]),np.array([3,4])]
b=[1,1]
e=zip(b,a)
sorted(e)
```

this causes the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

So when two elements in b are equal, it seems to proceed to sort according to a, but since a contains numpy arrays, the sorting algorithm complain when it tries to compare them.

Anyway, is this expected behaviour of sorted? In any case, I just want to sort according to b. If two elements are equal, the order does not matter. Any ideas on how to fix this without writing a sorting algorithm myself?

Comment: You get this ValueError when an boolean array is used in a context that expects a scalar boolean (e.g. `if`, `max`, or here the scalar sort).  Look at `1 < np.array([0,5])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shows up because `numpy.array` is not *comparable* in the sense of sorting, i.e. it doesn't return a `True` or `False` value (but another boolean array) when comparing two arrays, which is different from [lists comparison](https://docs.python.org/2.3/ref/comparisons.html).

If you only want to sort according to `b`, provide a key function to `sorted`:

```
sorted(e, key=lambda x: x[0])
# [(1, array([4, 5])), (1, array([3, 4]))]
```